A Certain Song/Zemiros Need The Name Of It
A Zemiros sung during Sheva Brachos. I forgot the name and need to know the song. I found two links of the song but can’t find the name of it.
https://youtu.be/S8SrMcf5v9w?si=M4mCxFx2dXSGKO7n (Belzer & Satmar Rebbetzins Dance Together)
https://youtu.be/lVlPHTQkL0E?si=GyTDJXm32PuzRfwd (From 51 Seconds and on)
https://youtu.be/vs_njzgqGtk?si=Lx1_sdaiBOshJ6uL (From 4:40 - 5:52)
If anybody can help. Thank you.

Here's another: https://youtu.be/etDfpl5pA38. Seems to be an excerpt from א-ל מסתתר.

Welcome to MiYodeya Tyler and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!
